# One host for multiple containers and switch container based on the path

Tags: docker, traefik

I use [traefik](https://traefik.io/#what) with a docker backend. Here is how I starter traefik:

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: proxy

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --web --docker --docker.domain=docker --logLevel=WARNING
    container_name: traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:dashboard.docker"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
```

---

I want 2 containers, one that is the [docker registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/), and a second one is a [UI for the registry](https://hub.docker.com/r/konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend/). I would like that all HTTP request like `registry.docker/v2/*` go through the registry container, but any other requests (`registry.docker/`, `registry.docker/repositories/20`, ...) go through the UI container.

Here it's what I tried:

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: proxy

services:
  registry:
    image: registry:2
    container_name: registry
    environment:
      -  REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:registry.docker, PathPrefix:/v2
      - traefik.frontend.port=5000

  registry-ui:
    image: konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend:v2
    container_name: registry-ui
    environment:
      - ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST=registry.docker
      - ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT=80
      - ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_USE_SSL=false
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:registry.docker
```

But all requests go through the `registry` container. What should I change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo here, based on files I have, here is a possible solution

Try this :

```
version: '2'

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: proxy

services:
  registry:
    image: registry:2
    container_name: registry
    environment:
      -  REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule: Host:registry.docker;PathPrefix:/v2
      - traefik.frontend.port: 5000

  registry-ui:
    image: konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend:v2
    container_name: registry-ui
    environment:
      - ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST=registry.docker
      - ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT=80
      - ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_USE_SSL=false
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule: Host:registry.docker
```

Comment: Yes, I changed `, PathPrefix:/v2` with `; PathPrefix:/v2`